# Error when deploying SSIS Package - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to deploy an SSIS via the Integration Services Deployment Wizard for SQL Server 2014 (Developer Edition). I am running Windows 8.1.

The error message is:

```
The required components for the 64-bit edition of Integration Services cannot 
be found. Run SQL Server Setup to install the required components. A .NET 
Framework error occured during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate     
"deploy_project_internal."
```

followed by an unhelpful stack trace.

I have installed the Integration Services feature via SQL Server Installation center and have verified that the 64-bit architecture components were installed. I have verified that the system PATH variable includes the directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn." I have verified that the SSIS service is running.

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Have you created the Integration Services instance on the database? The SSISDB will already exist, but you have to click through the wizard to actually get things turned on. Doubtful this is the issue but always like to cover the obvious before delving into the arcane

Comment: Yes, I have. The instance exists, and there doesn't appear to be anything abnormal about it.

Comment: Possibly [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135511/ssis-error-while-deploying-package)

Answer (score 0):

This is bug from Microsoft
[Click here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/850467/dtutil-installed-with-ssdtbi-for-vs2013-requires-other-installations)