# A .NET Framework error occured during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate - SSIS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to deploy a project in SSIS 2017 but I get the below error. I did some research on the web but nothing found could solve this issue, therefore I cannot deploy my project. Does anyone know what do I have to do? The suggested link to find help provided by Microsoft does not help at all.

```
**ERROR**

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
> routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The locale identifier (LCID) 2072
> is not supported by SQL Server. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:   
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean
> ignoreNonFatalMessages)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.InternalNextResult(Boolean
> ignoreNonFatalMessages)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReaderSmi.NextResult()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderSmi(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.GetServerProperty(String
> propertyName)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.GetSchemaVersion()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExecArgumentBuilder.ToString()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64
> deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString
> projectName) . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6522)
> 
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.1000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=6522&LinkId=20476
```

Comment: Let's cover the basics: has the integration services catalog been created on the target server? What is the target OS? How are you deploying? Do you have multiple versions of SSDT on the machine performing the deployment?

Comment: @billinkc - I did created ISC; Windows Server 2016; Right click on the project in SSDT->Deploy; No, only SSDT 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135511/ssis-error-while-deploying-package-the-locale-identifier-lcid-is-not-supported). The real issue was not related to Group Policy, as I believed in the first place, but to this part of the error and I had to change the language to `Locale` of `SQL` in `Registry Editor`:

> [...] The locale identifier (LCID) 2072 is not supported by SQL Server [...]

Hope it will help someone.