# Locale id is not supported on this operating system. LCID=8192

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact file (.SDF) with my C# Windows application. Some client systems are running it properly but a few of them generating errors.

```
Locale id is not supported on this operating system. LCID=8192
```

I made changes in the registry but in vain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The locale identifier (LCID) 8192 is not supported by SQL Server(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608814/the-locale-identifier-lcid-8192-is-not-supported-by-sql-server)

Comment: Actually, I am using SQL server compact files. Client machine has no SQL Server installed in their computers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "Lcid=1033" to the connection string

Comment: What do you think, this problem is due to database connectivity??

Comment: No, I it due to an unknown Windows locale

Comment: I changed the client machine locale setting, similar to my PC. The problem still the same.