T-SQL backup working but Maintenance plans failling with "Culture is not supported" SQL Server 2022
I am running a Windows 2022 server (last updates) and SQL Server 2022 CU 13 (16.0.4125.3) - SSMS 20.1 on different machines: W11, W2012 server, W2022 server.
I have a maintenance plan to backup all users databases of the SQL Server instance. As the databases are in full recovery model, I have 2 backup tasks 1 for Full (.bak) and 1 for Tlog (.trn).
When I execute the maintenance task, it fails with the error:
Date        04/06/2024 22:00:01
Log     Job History (DailyBackup-3Ret.Subplan_1)

Step ID 1
Server      Mysql\MyInstance
Job Name    DailyBackup-3Ret.Subplan_1
Step Name   Subplan_1
Duration    00:00:12
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: MyDomain\MycomputerAccount$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 16.0.4125.3 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  22:00:01  Error: 2024-06-04 22:00:02.74     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: {07EEC942-F074-49D7-ABFF-8AD3DCDFCC1C} Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp..." failed with the following error: "Culture is not supported.  Parameter name: culture  3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  Warning: 2024-06-04 22:00:02.74     Code: 0x80019002     Source: OnPreExecute      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  Error: 2024-06-04 22:00:11.53     Code: 0xC0024104     Source: Back Up Database Task      Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131501 (An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.  End Error  Warning: 2024-06-04 22:00:11.53     Code: 0x80019002     Source: Subplan_1      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  Error: 2024-06-04 22:00:11.53     Code: 0xC0024104     Source: {DE5AF745-A0CA-4FCE-AAE3-1720BDF1C9BF}      Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131501 (An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.  End Error  Warning: 2024-06-04 22:00:11.53     Code: 0x80019002     Source: OnPostExecute      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.  End Warning  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  22:00:01  Finished: 22:00:11  Elapsed:  10.406 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed

However, only the first database is backed up (.bak + .trn)
No matter the maintenance plan is created, executed, modified with SSMS 20.1 with client and SQL Server with English (Europe) or English (United States). I think I have tested all combinations...
When I copy the T-SQL of the maintenance plan then execute as a new query in SSMS, it's always working.
Any suggestion to make the maintenance plan work?
I have tried to copy the maintenance plan from another version of SQL, I am using this maintenance plan since SQL Server 2000 and was always working. The connection to the instance is good. I tried SSMS 20.1 and 19.x.

The error isn't coming from the BACKUP command. Post the full error. We can't guess which stored procedure is failing from just msdb..sp

Have you already seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1330069/please-help-me-how-can-i-fix-the-culture-is-not-su?cid=kerryherger and this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66232087/73226?

fyi, in full recovery mode that .trn backup task should run at the longest every 20 minutes, and possibly even more often. (If you're already doing this, good for you).

Thanks for your replies, I am actually unable to post the full error. @Panagiotis However, in the message this can be relevant: Source: Back Up Database Task      Description: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131501 (An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.). - Martin I have tried to recreate the maintenance plan from scratch. The problem occurs only with SQL server 2022 - Joel Thank you yor your advice, I will implement it.

@SwitchNikky you can post the full error. You already posted parts of it, post the rest as well in the question itself. SQL Server dialog boxes even have a Copy icon that copies the entire error contents

@MartinSmith I have tried to recreate the maintenance plan from scratch. The problem occurs only with SQL server 2022

There's nothing wrong with SQL Server 2002. We can't guess what happened if you don't post the actual error. Recreating the same thing won't fix anything.

On the other hand, Maintenance plans are not that useful because they're just ways of executing job steps in sequence. People don't create loops in maintenance plans, they just execute steps one after another. You can do the same thing as steps in a SQL Server Agent job.

You can configure a maintenance plan to log to a file. Have you tried that? What does the log show?

I am using maintenance plans essentially to create the names of the backup files from the users databases and keep easily 3 backups on disk.

You can configure naming in a SQL Server Agent job as well. Almost all DBAs use Ola Hallengren's backup and maintenance scripts, which allow you to specify naming patterns and which databases to backup using wildcards, verify backups etc, all with a single command. The first example in the backup page backs up all user databases with a single command, eg EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup  @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = 'C:\Backup', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'Y',...

Other examples in the same page show how to change the patterns, how to specify the number of retained files and in newer versions, how to backup to multiple files. Personally, I run the Integrity Checks command in an Agent Job step and if that succeeds I take daily full backups of SYSTEM databases and differential backups of USER_DATABASES. I don't want to back up a corrupt database and end up with a corrupt backup. Once per week I take full backups of all DBs.
